# Using LIKE operator to retrieve header codes only

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, sql-like

I have a simple question. I have a list of head codes and related sub codes:

- `100.001` *(head code)*
- `100.001.001-100.001.010` *(sub code)*
- `990.001` *(head code)*
- `990.001.001-120.001.010` *(sub code)*

The head codes are all listed, and underneath them their sub codes. All I want is to list just the head codes. I tried many variations, but none of the worked.

I also want to get the codes from `760.001` to `790.001` and I achieved it easily like this:

```
WHERE ACCOUNT_CODE >= '760'
AND   ACCOUNT_CODE <= '790'
```

Then I wanted to get just head codes:

```
WHERE ACCOUNT_CODE LIKE '7%0.00%`
```

But it still lists all of the codes from `760.001.001` to `790.001.010`. How do I filter them correctly?

Comment: question is not clear, specify what is desired result and how does data looks like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `_` wildcard to match only one character, instead of the `%` wildcard which matches any number of characters - for example:

```
ACCOUNT_CODE LIKE '7_0.00_'
```

Comment: ERROR: Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of substring function

Comment: @venom: Perhaps your question wasn't entirely clear (to me) - does every record contain subcodes, or do some contain only head codes?  I had assumed the former, but if it's the latter just add a further filter to your `WHERE` clause: e.g. `WHERE ... AND ACCOUNT_CODE RLIKE '^\d+\.\d+$'`.  (Actually, looking at your question again, I see that's what you were trying to do: you just needed to use the `_` wildcard to match only one character instead of the `%` wildcard that matches any number).

Comment: sorry, substring_index is not recognized, i used substring